# Questions about the Rank Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

POMA theorem 9.32: Suppose $m, n, r$ are nonnegative integers, $m \ge r,n\ge r$,$\mathbf{F}$ is a $C^1$ mapping of an open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\forall x\in E, \mathrm{rank}\ \mathbf{F}^\prime (x)=r$. For $\mathbf{a}\in E$, denote $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{F}^\prime (\mathbf{a})$, and let $P$ be a projection whose range is $\mathrm{Im}\ \mathbf{A}$. Then there are open sets $U$ and $V$  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbf{a} \in U, U\subset E$ and a injective $C^1$ mapping $\mathbf{H}:V\to U$ such that $(F\circ H)(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\varphi(A\mathbf{x})$ where $\varphi$ is a $C^1$ mapping from $A(V)$ to $\mathrm{Ker}\ A$.

Despite this lengthy statement, the idea is quite clear. But there is one point that confused me: what is $\mathbf{H}$, and what is the relation between sets $U$ and $V$  (I mean geometrical relation, for example, if $U$ and $V$ are very close to each other)?

Rudin proves this theorem by defining a mysterious function $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{I}+SP(F-A)$, whose inverse is $\mathbf{H}$, can anyone also explain why he construct $\mathbf{G}$ this way and what is the use of such $\mathbf{G}$?

Comment: honestly I think Rudin's statement and proof of the rank theorem are about as opaque as one can get. Conceptually the situation is much simpler: it's essentially a generalization of the linear algebra fact that a matrix of rank $r$ can always be modified by means of appropriate row and column operations (i.e by composing on the domain and target by linear isomorphisms) to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}  I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ (i.e such that the linear transformation is simply of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$, with zeros of appropriate size).

Comment: In the non-linear case what the theorem is saying is that if $F$ has derivative with constant rank, then we can find diffeomorphisms $\alpha,\beta$ on the domain and target respectively such that $\beta\circ F\circ\alpha^{-1}$ is equal to the above linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$. i.e by making a suitable "change of coordinates" (meaning compose with the appropriate diffeomorphisms) on both the domain and target, it follows that a non-linear constant rank mapping can always be simplified to the linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$.